# User can't change app.config of class library?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, permissions, appsettings

My application allows a user to make changes to user-scoped settings in its app.config file, and this works fine when running it through Visual Studio with the debugger. On deploying to the user's computer however, the application fails at startup with the following error:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)[organisation][app name]\p12qep40.tmp' is denied.

The application is split into 2 projects, a winforms app and a class library. Since the winforms app's app.config appears in the install folder as `[appname].exe.config`, I assume that the .tmp file is a runtime-generated version of the class library's app.config. Obviously the user doesn't have write access to the Program Files folder (and rightly so), so how do I make it so that the class library's settings (especially its user-scoped settings) are editable by the user?

---

Edit: Here's the code for writing settings back. ActiveConnString is scoped as a user setting, allowing the user to access a sandpit database or production.

```
Public Shared Property ActiveConnStringName() As String
    Get
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.ActiveConnString) Then
            My.Settings.ActiveConnString = "ProductionConnString"
        End If
        Return My.Settings.ActiveConnString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        My.Settings.ActiveConnString = value
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: How did your app allow users to make changes to settings? Paste the code. I guess it is related to UAC virtualization, but without seeing more about your app, that's only a guess.

Comment: @LexLi I've added a code sample.